# Recycle view row text overlaps on smaller devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am building a simple row layout to add data dynamicly inside my recycle view, so i builded a a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#cfcfcf">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/plantPhoto"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#c7c7c7"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.NexusBoldTextView
                    android:id="@+id/plantName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/emerald" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/starIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_star" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="15dp">


                <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.NexusBoldTextView
                    android:id="@+id/data"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/cameraForbiden"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/base" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cameraForbiden"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_no_photos" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/userIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_user" />

                <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.NexusBoldTextView
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userIcon"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/userIcon"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Filipe"
                    android:textColor="@color/base" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

the main problem on this approach is that when i check my solution on smaller devices the text at left orverlaps the text at right, one solution that i am searching is to decrease the content based on the device size, but didn't find that yet.

**This is what i get on a Nexus 5 for example:**

[image: bigger screan]

**this is what i get on a smaller device:**[image: smaller screan]

any help with this guys?

Thank you very much

Comment: use a different layout for smaller devices (https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: well i don't like too much that solution, since i have like 50 activities, if there is no other way i can give a try, but is strange that android can't adapt the screan content on different devices alone :S

Comment: In some sense Android adapts the view, otherwise the too wide items would stick out to the right and be no longer visible. But at some point, there is just not enough space left so another solution has to be found. For example arrange the two texts vertically instead of horizontally, or leave out some information. Only the designer can tell what's best here. Any automatic solution will suck sooner or later.

Comment: maybe you are right, thanks for the advice!

Comment: just a thing, what do you think about constraintLayout?

Comment: did it now, the elements at the bottom are to small it doesn't work well

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Linear layout** for this. You can assign **weight** to each item.

Try this code :

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cfcfcf">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/plantPhoto"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#c7c7c7"
                android:padding="0dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/plantName"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/starIcon"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_art_track_black_24dp" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/cameraForbiden"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_art_track_black_24dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/data"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2.5"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/password"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userIcon"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/userIcon"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Filipe"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/userIcon"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_art_track_black_24dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```